# Pandas: merge_asof-like solutions for merging two multi-indexed DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2` say, which are both multi-indexed.

At the first index level, both dataframes share the same keys (i.e. `df1.index.get_level_values(0)` and `df2.index.get_level_values(0)` contain the same elements). Those keys are unordered strings, such as `['foo','bar','baz']`.

At the second index level, both dataframes have timestamps which are ordered, but unequally spaced.

My question is as follows. I would like to merge `df1`and `df2` in such a way that, for each key at level 1, the values of `df2` should be inserted into `df1` without changing the order of `df1`.

I tried using `pd.merge`, `pd.merge_asof` and `pd.MultiIndex.searchsorted`. From the descriptions of those methods, it seems like one of them should do the trick for me, but I cannot figure out how. Ideally, I would like to find a solution that avoids looping over the keys in `index.get_level_values(0)`, since my dataframes can get large.

A few failed attempts for illustration:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(left=df1.reset_index(), right=df2.reset_index(),
                     left_on=[['some_keys', 'timestamps_df1']], right_on=[['some_keys', 'timestamps_df2']],
                     suffixes=('', '_2')
                     ) # after sorting
# FAILED

df2.index.searchsorted(df1, side='right') # after sorting
# FAILED
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Base on your description , here is the solution from `merge_asof`

```
df_merged = pd.merge_asof(left=df1.reset_index(), right=df2.reset_index(),
                     left_on=['timestamps_df1'], right_on=['timestamps_df2'],by='some_keys',
                     suffixes=('', '_2')
                     )
```

Comment: I'm somewhat ashamed, but I'm also very grateful. I won't forget the 'by' key again!